# Aerobic Chest exercises

Tags: exercise

I have better experience with aerobic exercises than anaerobic (ie unlike most other people). Even in regards to strength. Weightlifting never helped me; I peaked at some low point, and I stayed there. However, after some aerobic exercises, my max strength reached a relatively high level.

So, I am quite satisfied with my back strength due to a rowing machine. Skipping rope helped a lot with my calves. However, I have never been able to build up my chest significantly. Pushups have helped somewhat, but I feel even that may be a little too heavy (compared to what have helped other muscle groups).

I am not writing this to start an aerobic vs anaerobic discussion; I have had enough of those. Rather, I am looking for something of an equivalent to a rowing machine for the chest. I want suggestions for how I can train my chest aerobically.

Comment: There is *no* equivalent to a rowing machine / erg (aside from rowing proper). Not to mention that it's a full body movement, which complicates finding an equivalent even further.

Comment: Weightlifting is an aerobic exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any exercise can be done in an aerobic manner if you want it to, you just need to change its training modality and go for very low resistance and very high duration. I wouldn't recommend free weight exercises as you are going to reach a fatigued state pretty quickly and dropping a barbell on your face is a real risk, but most machines could be used pretty safely assuming your body proportions fall within a reasonable range of what the machine is built for. It won't make you strong (aerobic training doesn't build strength, almost by definition), but it will increase your endurance.

Examples:

- 50-100 repetitions for time (take as many breaks as you want, but try to complete the set as fast as possible)
- as many reps as possible for time (start with sets of 1 minute, increase progressively)